# C#: How to create an attribute on a method triggering an event when it is invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, events, methods, attributes

Is there a way in C# or .NET in general to create an attribute on a method which triggers an event when the method is invoked? Ideally, I would be able to run custom actions before and after the invocation of the method.

I mean something like this:

```
[TriggersMyCustomAction()]
public void DoSomeStuff()
{
}
```

I am totally clueless how to do it or if it possible at all, but [System.Diagnostic.ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) might do a similar thing in the background. I am not sure though.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that due to the circumstances of my specific case, performance is not really an issue.

Comment: The short answer is: yes accompanied by: I don't know how.  What you want to do is IL manipulation at compilation time to inject a call back on the first and final lines of your method.  The MS.VB assembly has an attribute that performs some IL manipulation (to make a class a non-static singleton).

Comment: @Tamas: I know your question was asked long time ago, but I came up with an answer. Hope it helps you. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is with [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).  It post-processes your IL and can do things like what you asked for.

Comment: I voted up this answer because it's my thought as well: you're gonna need some tool to run after the build to analyze your IL, look for methods with your attribute, and inject some event logic.

Comment: I just found out about PostSharp and went hunting for this question to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 27):

This concept is used in **[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) web applications.**

The **.NET Framework 4.x** provides several attributes which trigger actions, e.g.: `ExceptionFilterAttribute` (handling exceptions), `AuthorizeAttribute` (handling authorization). Both are defined in `System.Web.Http.Filters`.

You could for instance define your own authorization attribute as follows:

```cs
public class myAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // do any stuff here
        // it will be invoked when the decorated method is called
        if (CheckAuthorization(actionContext)) 
           return true; // authorized
        else
           return false; // not authorized
    }

}
```

Then, in your **controller** class you decorate the methods which are supposed to use your authorization as follows:

```cs
[myAuthorization]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id)
{
    // ... your code goes here
    response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); // return OK status
    return response;
}
```

Whenever the `Post` method is invoked, it will call the `IsAuthorized` method inside the `myAuthorization` Attribute *before* the code inside the `Post` method is executed.

If you return `false` in the `IsAuthorized` method, you signal that authorization is not granted and the execution of the method `Post` aborts.

---

To understand how this works, let's look into a different example: The **`ExceptionFilter`**, which allows filtering exceptions by using attributes, the usage is similar as shown above for the `AuthorizeAttribute` (you can find a more detailed description about its usage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)).

To use it, derive the `DivideByZeroExceptionFilter` class from the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` as shown [here](http://blog.karbyn.com/articles/handling-errors-in-web-api-using-exception-filters-and-exception-handlers/), and override the method `OnException`:

```cs
public class DivideByZeroExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is DivideByZeroException)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage() { 
                Content = new StringContent("A DIV error occured within the application.",
                                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), 
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the following demo code to trigger it:

```cs
[DivideByZeroExceptionFilter]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    // Just for demonstration purpose, it
    // causes the DivideByZeroExceptionFilter attribute to be triggered:
    throw new DivideByZeroException(); 

    // (normally, you would have some code here that might throw 
    // this exception if something goes wrong, and you want to make
    // sure it aborts properly in this case)
}
```

Now that we know how it is used, we're mainly interested in the implementation. The following code is from the .NET Framework. It uses the interface `IExceptionFilter` internally as a contract:

```cs
namespace System.Web.Http.Filters
{
    public interface IExceptionFilter : IFilter
    {
        // Executes an asynchronous exception filter.
        // Returns: An asynchronous exception filter.
        Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(
                    HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, 
                    CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The `ExceptionFilterAttribute` itself is defined as follows:

```cs
namespace System.Web.Http.Filters
{
    // Represents the attributes for the exception filter.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, 
            Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public abstract class ExceptionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, 
            IExceptionFilter, IFilter
    {
        // Raises the exception event.
        // actionExecutedContext: The context for the action.
        public virtual void OnException(
            HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
        }
        // Asynchronously executes the exception filter.
        // Returns: The result of the execution.
        Task IExceptionFilter.ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(
            HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext == null)
            {
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionExecutedContext");
            }
            this.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
            return TaskHelpers.Completed();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync`, the method `OnException` is called. Because you have overridden it as shown earlier, the error can now be handled by your own code.

---

There is also a commercial product available as mentioned in OwenP's answer, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), which allows you to do that easily. [Here](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception#intercepting-method) is an example how you can do that with PostSharp. Note that there is an Express edition available which you can use for free even for commercial projects.

**PostSharp Example** (see the link above for full description):

```cs
public class CustomerService
{
    [RetryOnException(MaxRetries = 5)]
    public void Save(Customer customer)
    {
        // Database or web-service call.
    }
}
```

Here the attribute specifies that the `Save` method is called up to 5 times if an exception occurs. The following code defines this custom attribute:

```cs
[PSerializable]
public class RetryOnExceptionAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public RetryOnExceptionAttribute()
    {
        this.MaxRetries = 3;
    }

    public int MaxRetries { get; set; }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        int retriesCounter = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                args.Proceed();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                retriesCounter++;
                if (retriesCounter > this.MaxRetries) throw;

                Console.WriteLine(
                  "Exception during attempt {0} of calling method {1}.{2}: {3}",
                  retriesCounter, args.Method.DeclaringType, args.Method.Name, e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You need some sort of Aspect oriented framework.  PostSharp will do it, as will [Windsor](http://castleproject.org/container).

Basically, they subclass your object and override this method...

then it becomes:

```
//proxy
public override void DoSomeStuff()
{
     if(MethodHasTriggerAttribute)
        Trigger();

     _innerClass.DoSomeStuff();
}
```

of course all this is hidden to you.   All you have to do is ask Windsor for the type, and it will do the proxying for you.  The attribute becomes a (custom) facility I think in Windsor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ContextBoundObject and IMessageSink. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/magazine/cc301356(en-us).aspx

Be warned that this approach has a severe performance impact compared with a direct method call.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. It refers to: *MSDN Magazine Issues and Downloads,* listing all issues of this magazine. Because the answer does not provide any further information, it doesn't help without a working link in place.

Comment: just in same if someone is looking for example, can check the git https://github.com/stdeepak22/CSharp_Method_Interceptor

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it with just an attribute, but using [proxy classes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicproxy.aspx) and reflection you could have a class that knows to intercept instantiations of the classes in which you have attributed methods.

Then the proxy class can trigger an event whenever the attributed methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute gives information, they are metadata.  I don't know of a way to do this offhand, someone might.

You could look at partial methods in .NET which allow you to do some lightweight event handling.  You provide the hooks and let someone else handle the implementation.  If the method isn't implemented the compiler just ignores it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the poor man's solution: see the decorator pattern.