# c# trigger pre and post method calls like mvc actionfilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

Is there a way to get the functionality of action filters in asp.net mvc where you can call and manipulate action parameters pre the method executing and post method call to update/view the return type data but in a standard c# class library class method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Attribute to trigger an event on invoking a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226420/c-sharp-attribute-to-trigger-an-event-on-invoking-a-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) is an example of a tool that can help you get there. A common example is to have a class auto-implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which is boring or tedious, or to spit out a bunch of logging statements before and after a method call, without having to manually write that instrumentation in code.

Hope that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Tons of great examples here: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=postsharp+asp.net+mvc

Comment: any open source alternative to postsharp you would recommend?

Comment: I feel like PostSharp was open source at one time ... maybe it was just free to use. It looks like there is still a community edition that is free. I have used PostSharp in the past and it seems to work well. At a basic level, you could use Castle's DynamicProxy or LinFu, but the use case is different. At least now you know the magic words to search for! :)