# Record Time Custom Attribute C#

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I am trying to write a custom attribute which will log start time of a method.

Here it is my code :

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                CompareBusinessUnits();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        [RecordTime]
        private static void CompareBusinessUnits()
        {

            // to do something
        }


    }


    public class RecordTimeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public void PrintStartTime()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time " + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

But console window does not show start time. I want to print the time when the method starts.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/226440/2877982

Comment: Just defining a custom attribute doesn't actually make any code run. You have to write reflection code that searches for such attributes and invokes the appropriate functionality. Attributes aren't magic.

Comment: This is not what attributes are designed for